# Memo keeps displaying same currency value even though amount is increased in a for loop

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

For some reason this code will only output the same as the entered number as in the TextEdit. The format of the output should be like

1. $3000
2. $3300

and so on.

```
procedure TfrmProjection.BtnCalculateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  counter, i : integer;
  total, sales, average, projsales : double;
begin
  sales := StrtoFloat(edtSales.Text);
  redOutput.Lines.Add('INCREASE IN SALES');
  for i := 1 to 12 do
    redOutput.Lines.Add(FloattoStr(i) + #9 + #9 + FloattoStrf(sales, ffCurrency, 9, 2));
  sales:= sales * 1.1;
end;
```

Does anyone know how one would be able to rectify this?

Comment: Same mistake as previous question. Do you know how to debug yet? Until you do it will cripple your attempts to learn and improve.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint on the `for` line and stepping through 2 iterations of the loop would have told you what was wrong, in far less time than it took you to come here, click the *Ask Question* button, and type your first sentence of text (much less the rest, copying/pasting/formatting the code, etc). Learn to use the debugger, and you'll stop being totally helpless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out a begin end block, `so sales * 1.1` is never called until the end.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  counter, i: integer;
  sales, average, projsales : double;
begin
  sales := StrtoFloat(edtSales.Text);
  redOutput.Lines.Add('INCREASE IN SALES');
  for i := 1 to 12 do
  begin
    redOutput.Lines.Add(FloattoStr(i) + #9 + #9 + FloattoStrf(sales, ffCurrency, 9, 2));
    sales:= sales * 1.1;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that :( Thanks for the help